# how to use only class properties in flowtype for validation of parameters?

Tags: flowtype

I have the following code

```
class User {
   id: string,
   name: string,
   email: string
   isAdmin: boolean,
};

const isAdmin = (user: User): boolean => {
   if (user.isAdmin) return true;

   return false;
}
```

I would like that isAdmin accept another object that is not from class User, but it has isAdmin property.

example:

```
isAdmin({isAdmin: true})
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can define a type for that:

```
/* @flow */

class User {
   id: string;
   name: string;
   email: string;
   isAdmin: boolean;
};

type HasAdmin = {
  isAdmin: boolean;
}

const isAdmin = (hasAdmin: HasAdmin): boolean => {
   if (hasAdmin.isAdmin) return true;

   return false;
}

isAdmin(new User());

isAdmin({isAdmin: true});
```

You can see the code in action [here](https://flow.org/try/#0PQKgBAAgZgNg9gdzCYAoVBjGBDAzrsAVVwFMAnMAb1TFoEsATALjFwBcy6A7AcwG4atLtgC2JFu068BtMCRHY6MCR279BYOrgCCDEdxYAjOHBglsXAQF8BqNgE8ADiTAAJPLv1cwAXiqCtTwMwY1NzS1QrdAw4LnZNHT1uXzAACgALDySuFndErwBKIxMzC18APn9ZOig0zPzuADpA7IKwMhI2AFcybw4ukltZDu7esChsGFJrdBavVK4SJGJyVIKC2znuVMotnLB+kisN1CA)

Comment: I think this is the only way, but I would like to avoid creating another type just for that. However this works, so let's move on \o/

Comment: @SibeliusSeraphini you can "inline" the type. Have a look to Aria's answer. But personally I prefer to explicitly create the type for lisability.

Answer (score 1):

You can use structural typing:

```
class User {
   id: string
   name: string
   email: string
   isAdmin: boolean
};

const isAdmin = (user: {isAdmin: boolean}): boolean => {
   if (user.isAdmin) return true;

   return false;
}

isAdmin({isAdmin: true})
isAdmin(new User())
```